# iperf3 UDP tuning

Tags: network, networking, testing, iperf3

I am trying to test throughput in the network. But when i start iperf3 client for sending UDP packets it sends TCP SYN packets. Why does it behave like this? (it should not send udp tcp syn while connectiing to UDP server)

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's how iperf3.x works.

The "client" wants to establish a control channel to the "server" before any UDP transfer is started. That's why you can observe some TCP before the UDP transfer starts. I haven't checked, but I believe that there is also a separate control channel connection when running TCP tests.

In contrast, iPerf 1.7 and 2.0.x do not require a TCP control channel connection to be established in UDP mode, they just "blast away".

That makes iPerf 2.0.x a tool to use with great caution in environments where (upstream) bandwidth is scarce: It is all too easy to inadvertedly start a 50Mbit/s UDP stream from a client that will completely oversubscribe the 10Mbit/s DSL upstream. On the other hand, it makes iPerf a great tool to test and validate QoS configurations across a WAN.